# Why my regex can not work in Python?

Tags: python, regex

What I am trying to match is something like this:

```
public FUNCTION_NAME
FUNCTION_NAME proc near
......

FUNCTION_NAME endp
```

FUNCTION_NAME can be :

```
version_etc
version_etc_arn
version_etc_ar
```

and my pattern is:

```
pattern = "public\s+" + func_name + "[\s\S]*" + func_name + "\s+endp"
```

and match with:

```
match = re.findall(pattern, content)
```

So currently I find if the fuction_name equals version_etc, then it will match
all the version_etc_arn, version_etc_ar and version_etc.....

which means if the pattern is :

"public\s+" + "version_etc" + "[\s\S]*" + "version_etc" + "\s+endp"

then it will match:

```
public version_etc_arn
version_etc_arn proc near
......

version_etc_arn endp

public version_etc_ar
version_etc_ar proc near
......

version_etc_ar endp

public version_etc
version_etc proc near
......

version_etc endp
```

And I am trying to just match:

```
public version_etc
version_etc proc near
......

version_etc endp
```

Am I wrong? Could anyone give me some help?

THank you!

Comment: Also, you should always be using raw strings when dealing with regexes (to handle escape sequences correctly), and you don't need `[\s\S]` in Python; `.` works just like it if you specify `re.DOTALL` when compiling/using the regex.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Hi Tim, I modified my question, is it clear now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[\s\S]*` matches 0-or-more of anything, including the `_arn` that you are trying to exclude. Thus, you need to require a whitespace after `func_name`:

```
pattern = r"(?sm)public\s+{f}\s.*^{f}\s+endp".format(f=func_name)
```

Comment: Oooh. Format string syntax. Unfortunately, I can only upvote this once.